# Wordpress $query->set() got an error Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on string

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to display the custom post type that created by acf to *order* it according to `meta_key` which is **order**

This is my code

```
function __construct(){
    add_action("pre_get_posts",array($this,"orderlist"));
    add_action("init",array($this,"orderlist"));
}

function orderlist($query){
    $query->set('meta_key','order');
    $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
}
```

When I tried to run this code I got a

> Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on string

I have followed [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Answer (score -1):

Just remove this code and it will work

`add_action("init",array($this,"orderlist"));`